# "resource" or "reference" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Searched for a super-category for various reference materials and resources on information about Buddhism which covers podcasts, books, videos, retreats, etc., didn't find one. Not sure if this is the way to go about suggesting a new tag, couldn't find info on that either.

In a recent post I made a reference to a resource. Would a tag that includes all types of references and resources be helpful, an umbrella for all the different media and forms rather than applying each one individually in order to locate all types of available information?

Comment: We've got the media tag. And also a book tag. The reference-request tag covers text based resources that answer specific question. But it's a good question